# What is the meaning of the following matlab notation?

Tags: matlab

I want to write this matlab code in python but I do not know what LEV(1:n+1:n^2) = 0; or LEV(i,:) means. Can anyone explain me what are this notation? Thank you!

```
function A = ILU_p(A,p)

n = length(A);
LEV = inf(n);
LEV(find(A)) = 0;
LEV(1:n+1:n^2) = 0;  

for i = 2:n   
    for k = 1:i-1  
        if LEV(i,k) > p
            continue
        end
        A(i,k) = A(i,k) / A(k,k);
        A(i,k+1:n) = A(i,k+1:n) - A(i,k) * A(k,k+1:n);
        LEV(i,k+1:n) = min([LEV(i,k+1:n); LEV(i,k) + LEV(k,k+1:n) + 1]);
    end
    A(i,find(LEV(i,:)>p)) = 0; 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sets up a vector of values to be used in an index. If n=10 then the below would yield a row vector of `[1 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 100]`

```
1:n+1:n^2
```

Since LEV is set up as an nxn matrix and the above row vector picks up the diagonal elements, i.e., LEV(1) = LEV(1,1), LEV(12) = LEV(2,2), etc.

LEV(i,:) is MATLAB's shorthand for referencing all columns in row i.